# How to create variable in visual studio workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-variable

I am first time creating Workflow in visual studio for SharePoint 2010. Now i need to create variable (Workflow variable) in my workflow but i am not getting any reference or tutorials for create variable in workflow.

Can anyone please give any reference of how to create variable in workflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check [How to: Create SharePoint 2013 Workflows using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn584771.aspx) on how to create variables and arguments on activity-level:

> **5.** Output pane displays information about workflow activity elements – variables, arguments, and import.
>
> [image: Blockquote]

General concept of variables and arguments in WWF (not SharePoint-specific) is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236889/sharepoint-workflow-global-variables-in-c-sharp-workflow-project might be useful to decide your tactics of storing 'global' variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i am using SharePoint workflow 2010 not 2013. Is there any action in SP2010 workflow?